# Jquery: Datepicker on an appended row in a table is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have created a table that inside of it, contains a column in a row that lets the user picks the date. The datepicker works on the static text field, but on the one generated by the click of a button, it is not working.(The row is appended, but the datepicker will not appear on the newly generated row.)

This is the code for the table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class = "table" id="dynamic_admin_add_event_time">
<thead>
<th>Event Date</th>
<th>Event Start</th>
<th>Event Ends</th>
<th></th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="dateEvent" name="admin_add_event_date[]"  class="form-control" required></td>
<td><input type="text" id="startTime" name="admin_add_start_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>
<td><input type="text" id="endTime" name="admin_add_end_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>
<td><button type="button" name=button_add_event_time id="add_event_time" class="btn btn-success">Add More Event</button></td>   
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is the code for the datepicker:

```
  $("#dateEvent").datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: true,
  format: "dddd, MMM D YYYY"
  });
```

And this is the one for the jquery for generating the rows:

```
$('#add_event_time').click(function(){

        i++;

        $('#dynamic_admin_add_event_time').append(
            '<tr id="row'+i+'">' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="dateEvent"name="admin_add_event_date[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="startTime" name="admin_add_start_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="endTime" name="admin_add_end_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
            '<td><button type="button" name="button_remove_event_time" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove Event</button></td>' +
            '</tr>');
 });
```

Can you guys help me by with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: convert  `id="dateEvent"` to `class="dateEvent"` and use `$(".dateEvent").datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: true,
  format: "dddd, MMM D YYYY"
  });`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/ Try this demo. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("#dynamic_admin_add_event_time").on("click", "#dateEvent", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: true,
        format: "dddd, MMM D YYYY"
    });
});
```

Comment: Yours work, but i have to click on the table area to get the datepicker since the ##dynamic_admin_add_event_time is the id of the table. I've tried changing the #dynamic_admin_add_event_time to the other buttons, but it doesn't work. Got any tips?

Comment: Got it working now, i changed the click into a focus. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pleasure @teddygamer

Answer (score 3):

Button click inside redefine to `reinitialize` datetimepicker load like

**datetimepicker assign**

```
$(".dateEvent").datetimepicker({ 
   useCurrent: true, 
   format: "dddd, MMM D YYYY" 
});
```

**Script**

```
$('#add_event_time').click(function(){
   i++;
    $('#dynamic_admin_add_event_time').append(
        '<tr id="row'+i+'">' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="dateEvent" class="form-control dateEvent" name="admin_add_event_date[]"  required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="startTime" name="admin_add_start_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="endTime" name="admin_add_end_event[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
        '<td><button type="button" name="button_remove_event_time" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove Event</button></td>' +
        '</tr>');
    $( ".dateEvent" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: @teddygamer  if it not worked then why it is marked?

Comment: <td><input type="text" id="dateEvent" class="form-control dateEvent" name="admin_add_event_date[]"  required></td>

Comment: Ah sorry, my hand slipped and mis-clicked it.